# pip installing dj_static, import error

Tags: python, django

Whenever I try to run this specific project I cloned via foreman start, I get

```
13:13:32 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
13:13:32 web.1  |     from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info
13:13:32 web.1  | ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info
```

Mind you I am running this in a virtual env, and I used pip install -r requirements/dev.txt to install what I needed. Someone mentioned something about adding "it" to my PYTHONPATH, but I have no idea what "it" is and how to do that. Am I adding dj_static to my PYTHONPATH? Because I thought it would have been automatically added given I used pip install to get it. Is this true?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: reinstall django in your venv

Comment: A MILLION THANK YOU's! I must ask, how did you know?

Comment: You're welcome. The package was there but got corrupted somehow or you have two installations. I  will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have installed two different versions or you have changed some file in the installation. 
Just reinstall django in your venv and it will work.